# Clip raster with polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

QGIS 2.18.2 from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis. Just reinstalled all packages, GDAL complete, NumPy, and matplotlib. Then reinstalled the app.

I created a polygon shapefile by drawing. But I don't see under Raster any options to clip. I want to clip a georeferenced scanned map.

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html mentions Raster ‣ Extraction ‣ Clipper. I don't have this option.

Other tutorials show similar options.

[My Raster menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir3py.png) only have three options.

What am I missing?

Comment: Under the menu 'Plugins', can you open 'Manage and Install Plugins" to open up Plugins Manger? There you can find **GdalTools**. Check it on and close the manager.

Comment: Installed by default and it shows under "Installed." And the reinstall does nothing. It's listed as v 1.2.29.

Comment: One strange thing to me is you have georeferencer tool under the menu. To figure out what is happening, can you try to activate other tools such as **Heatmap** plugin? It should appear in the Raster menu, too.

Comment: Thank you. Got me thinking. I reinstalled gdal AFTER (contrary to instructions) installing QGIS, rebooted my Mac and now I see the Raster options. BTW click on My Raster menu in the original post to see what I had originally

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of any help. Congrats anyway :-)

Comment: @Kazuhito. You did help. You got me thinking harder about GDAL. I wrote the buy who provides the Mac installers about it.